# POSTGIS Optimize query

Tags: postgis, centroid

I have a table with a column "multip" type GEOMETRY which contains a multipolygon.
Each multipolygon contains several polygons.
My table is very large (12 millions records).

I need a fast query on my table which extracts all lines of my table which has polygons which are in a map visible frame (latmin, latmax, lngmin, lngmax).

I currently use the ST_Dwithin operator with the following query:

```
SELECT id, mydata FROM mytable WHERE ST_Dwithin(multip, ST_TRANSFORM(ST_MakeEnvelope(" + myframe.join(',') + ", 4326), 2154),0) LIMIT 100
```

but this request is too slow.

Is there a way to speed up the query using a simplified version of the multipolygon ? For example by building a new column with polygon centroids instead?

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: For query performance related question always post the query plan: `explain (analyse, buffers) ...`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for taking the time to answer!
I already had an index on my column. Using "&&" or ST_INTERSECTS did not improve performance.

But I finally found a solution : I created a new column containing only the centroids of the polygons instead of the multipolygon itself and it appears to be way more effective than intersecting with polygons.

Comment: If using `&&` here does not help, your index is not properly set up - wrong CRS or type, or stale statistics.

Comment: Although it seems a reasonable approach you might take into account that a centroid of a multipolygon might be very misleading, e.g. the centroid of UK if you consider the Falkland Islands (close to Argentina) ;) Not to mention that operation like touch won't be possible anymore. I would rather invest more time in analysing the query plan instead of simplifying the data set so drastically. cheers

Comment: Since one of the geometries is a constant and you're applying limit, you could switch to [`order by multip<<->>st_transform(...) limit 100`](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_centroid_nd.html) bbox centroid distance without having to pull out the centroid to another column, or the same thing with `<#>` or `<->`. Added benefit of `<<->>` is you don't get a random 100 that just intersect, you get the 100 that's closest to the center. It may work in tandem with `&&` if you have some cases where there's typically less than a 100 intersecting.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a [spatial index](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/indexing.html) on your table.

Try this

```
CREATE INDEX multip ON my table USING GIST (geom);
```

It might work, and might not, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Hello. Thanks, but spatial index is already in place.

Answer (score 0):

`ST_DWithin` is a swiss army knife, even to mock the functionity of `ST_Intersects` - but its prime dependency for peformance is the product of the vertex counts of the geometries in consideration.

The spatial index efficiency is generally being defeated by arbitrarily large and widespread multi-part geometries - in fact, it is not only recommended to dump multi-part geometries into their components and index those, but also good practice to `ST_SubDivide` areal geometries even further in order to reduce per-component vertex count!

---

With that being said, you're still in luck: since all you want is bounding box overlaps between your geometries and a viewport rectangle, just use the appropriate, index driven `&&` operator instead:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  mytable
WHERE
  multip && ST_Transform(ST_MakeEnvelope(" + myframe.join(',') + ", 4326), 2154)
LIMIT
  100
;
```